# How do I create UserControl that binds "normally"?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, user-controls

I will explain what I mean.

Let's say I wrapped TextBox into UserControl and expose property **Id**
In order to bind to this property, it has to be Dependency property. Fine, here we go(notice stupid dance with OnIdChanged calls property setter so we get INotifyPropertyChanged working):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IdProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Id", typeof(string), typeof(MyTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(OnIdChanged));

public string Id
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(IdProperty);
            }

            set
            {
                this.SetValue(IdProperty, value);
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }

private static void OnIdChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (d as Lookup).Id = e.NewValue as string;
        }
```

So, this seems like all I need. I create another User control. Drop MyTextBox on it:

```
    <Lookup:MyTextBox Id="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Path=DataSource.CurrentItem.DeviceId, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

As you see - I had to use DataContextProxy. To be honest, it's little bit of magic for me, I did it once and tried it now when regular way wasn't binding. How should I code my user control so I can bind to it like so?

```
        <Lookup:MyTextBox Id="{Binding Path=CurrentItem.DeviceId, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

This is how I can bind TextBox next to my custom one and it works as expected. What is the secret?

**EDIT**

Below is 2 screenshots. First one shows how what I get as a source when I bind to Lookup control (custom UserControl) - points to SELF

Second one - next field in my XAML - is regular textbox, binds to same CurrentItem but it sources from my ViewModel
[image]
[image]

**EDIT 2**

I figured why DataContext was pointing to UserControl itself. I figured **why** but do not understand why..

In my UserControl (Lookup) code behind after initializiation I set this.DataContext = this so inside control it binds to internal properties. Somehow it propogated to parent ViewModel. After I changed this code to LayoutRoot.DataContext = this - issue resolved. But I don't understand why it behaves like this and I still can't get good property routing through..

Comment: @Xin CurrentItem is an object property of my ViewModel. It's a business object with INotifyPropertyChange and INotifyDataError.. Nothing special. Just an object. I bind to it with regular controls directly. But with my UserControl I have to go through proxy for some reason

Comment: DataContextProxy is just a helper that helps the MyTextBox to find the DataContext of its parent control. I guess your CurrentItem is one level higher than the MyTextBox, that why you will always need this proxy, or I guess, in this case you can use ElementName binding instead of DataContextProxy, the latter is needed for DataGrid normally as the ElementName binding doesn't work.

Comment: @Xin See my edit. And I'm not sure how ElementName works

Comment: yes, I assume the first one doesn't work and the second one does? This probably means, CurrentItem is a property inside your MaintainDeviceViewModel, so it works. While in your first one, the source is Lookup which is one level lower than the MaintainDeviceViewModel, and this is why you need the DataContextProxy.

Comment: @Xin Correct. But WHY? XAML you see is on a same page. Lookup and TextBox declared next to each other, they not on different levels. And my View bound to my ViewModel with CurrentItem. But as you see in debugger - when it binds Lookup - it thinks that it's data context control itself. When I have controls next to each other - I expect to bind them using identical code

Comment: Also you can try to use ElementName binding like, <lookup:MyTextBox Id="{Binding DataContext.CurrentItem.DeviceId, ElementName=LayoutRoot, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

Comment: Try to remove Repository and Container bindings, they might somehow change the DataContext. And test if you have the same source.

Comment: @Xin ElementName binding works, but still. WOnder why it's necessary. I tried without Repository and Container - does same thing. Trying to bind to Lookup itself

Comment: there must be something inside LookUp that sets the DataContext to something else

Comment: @Xin - yes it was - see my Edit2. I need to set it inside Lookup so I can bind controls to Lookup's context. So, I need to pass properties from ViewModel to Lookup but inside lookup I need to bind to itself. See how I solved it but it's still not intuitive why it did that.

Comment: take a look at my answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586741/usercontrol-blendability-wp7/7593318#comment9215855_7593318, might help you understand how the user control binding works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I covered this issue in a blog post which [I wrote some time ago](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2009/08/the-mini-viewmodel-pattern/). If you set the DataContext of the UserControl to itself, you can no longer place it within another UserControl or Window and expect it to inherit the DataContext of its parent. This means that you cannot just sit it in your view and specify bindings to your view model. The reasons for this is that you have blocked inheritence of your ViewModel DataContext. Any properties exposed by your UserControl will have their binding Source set to the UserControl.

The solution is to set DataContext of some element *within* the UserControl to the UserControl itself. Most typically you would set the immediate child of the UserControl.